# back button not shown on home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

inside my jquery mobile website inside header I have navbar which has back button besides other buttons. I want to display this back button only if visitor is not on the homepage and without disabling ajax.

how this can be done?

Comment: As I reckon when reading your question you are building a single page application, that is, you only load the page once and navigate to different views locally using javascript. If so, please extend your question. If not, you can simply refrain from rendering the button when you render the home page, so the question wouldn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('homepagename')!=-1) {
        $('backbutton').hide()
    }
    else {
        $('backbutton').show()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to each tab button.

```
$('#HomeTab').click(function() {
    $('#backbutton').css('display', 'block');
});

$('#SecondTab').click(function() {
   $('#backbutton').css('display', 'none');
});
```